# Adding the Authorization header in the flutter code gives back an error response whereas the same request works fine in the postman

Tags: flutter, dart-async, flutter-http, flutter-future

I am having a weird error in flutter where just adding an authorization header allows me to have an error.

**Current Problem I am having,**

```
  postData(data, apiUrl) async {
    var fullUrl = _url + apiUrl;

    var at = await _accessToken;
    print('access token is $at');

    return await http.post(
      Uri.parse(fullUrl),
      body: jsonEncode(data),
      encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8"),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $at',    <---------------- Adding this line of code prints an error in the console
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
    );
```

In my code, if I add the `Authorization` header that I am pointing to with an arrow in the above code I receive an error on the console that says,

> D/libc-netbsd(32217): [getaddrinfo]: mtk
> hostname=host_name_i_provided; servname=(null);
> cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0; app_uid=10217; ai_addrlen=0;
> ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0 D/libc-netbsd(32217):
> getaddrinfo: host_name_i_provided get result from proxy >>
> E/flutter (32217): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)]
> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 3,
> character 1) E/flutter (32217):  E/flutter (32217): ^
> E/flutter (32217):  E/flutter (32217): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail
> (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5) E/flutter (32217): #1
> _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1271:9) E/flutter (32217): #2
> _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:936:22) E/flutter (32217): #3
> _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10) E/flutter (32217): #4      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:506:36)
> E/flutter (32217): #5      JsonCodec.decode
> (dart:convert/json.dart:157:41) E/flutter (32217): #6
> _RescueMeFormPageState.submitData (package:redcross/Pages/Disaster/rescue_me_form_page.dart:57:21)
> E/flutter (32217):  E/flutter (32217):

But if I remove that header, I get the following valid response,

> I/flutter (32217): {status: 400, data: {code: TokenException, message:
> Authorization Token not found}}

**I can not figure out why I am getting this error.**

A few more things I would like to point out is, the `$at` variable holds the correct access token. I verified this by adding print statements. So the line of code `'Authorization': 'Bearer $at',` is valid.

Also If I do the same request from the postman I get a valid response.

Can someone please help me figure out a solution to this error. Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with token it is with JSON parsing check the code at which you are parsing the response.